# Problems with generated lint.xml from ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-lint

I work in a team with multi-platform environments and we're having some issues with the generated lint.xml file. This file is also used by our Jenkins build system which is running on Mac OS X (it needs to be a Mac because this system will be used to build Android and iOS applications).

The thing is, we need to ignore a Lint check for a specific file in the libs folder. When I do that in Windows, I get his: `<ignore path="libs\FlurryAgent.jar" />` but Lint running on the Mac with Jenkins doesn't understand the backslash and it will ignore the lint.xml file. No good...

We changed the backslash to a forward slash and it's now working on the Mac. But then it stops working on my Windows machine, it doesn't understand the forward slash.

Is there a way to make the forward slash work in both systems without messing with the slash all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry. That's a bug in lint. I'll fix that, but I don't think there is a workaround. (For some issues, you can insert a @SuppressLint annotation or a tools:ignore attribute in the corresponding XML, but that doesn't work for things like warnings on icon files.)